# Nginx Lua launching hostapd on Linux with os.execute

Tags: linux, nginx, lua

I can hit my Nginx Webserver running on Linux with openresty and successfully run many different commands. The only command I **cannot** run is hostapd with lua's os.execute. Please see the following code. The only command that does not work is the last one.

Failing command:

```
set_command_status = os.execute("source /etc/profile ; /usr/bin/hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf >> /tmp/hostapd.log 2>&1")
    ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Hostapd launch status: " .. set_command_status)
    ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Done Restarting HOSTAPD")
```

Complete code:

```
-- Restart hotspot with new name
ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Restarting HOSTAPD: " .. json_table.hotspot_name)
set_command_status = os.execute("kill -9 `pgrep -f hostapd`")
ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Kill status: " .. set_command_status)
set_command_status = os.execute("cp /mnt/apps/hostapd.conf /tmp/")
ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Copy status: " .. set_command_status)
set_command_status = os.execute("find /tmp -type f -name \"hostapd.conf\" | xargs sed -i -e \"s/wpa_passphrase=asdfasdf/wpa_passphrase=password/g\"")
ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Hostapd config password status: " .. set_command_status)
set_command_status = os.execute("find /tmp -type f -name \"hostapd.conf\" | xargs sed -i -e \"s/ssid=nightcrawler/ssid=FC3550-" .. json_table.hotspot_name .. "/g\"")
ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Hostapd config ssid status: " .. set_command_status)
set_command_status = os.execute("source /etc/profile ; /usr/bin/hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf >> /tmp/hostapd.log 2>&1")
ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Hostapd launch status: " .. set_command_status)
ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Done Restarting HOSTAPD")

-- Done
ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Success setting HotSpot Name")

ngx.exit(ngx.OK)
```

The log says:

```
$ cat /tmp/hostapd.log
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
```

How can I launch hostapd from nginx and openresty this way?

Comment: Do you get any output in /tmp/hostapd.log?

Comment: I've edited the post with the log contents - it seems as though it starts and then stops without any error messages.